# Flash: dynamically adding events code to instances possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to make a movieclip invisible initially but i dont want to set it manually within the properties in flash because i cant then see it on the scene.

I was hoping i could add some code like so:

**MC Frame one.**

```
this.onClipEvent(load)
{
this._alpha = 0;
}
```

but I cannot. How can i set the MC _alpha to 0 for all instances without adding it manually to each instance or setting it in the properties?

edit: or creating a class for it just to set the alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using this code, which does what i want. But i hate it.

```
    var once:Boolean;

    if (once == null) {
        once = true;
        this._alpha = 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's basically emulating the onClipEvent(Load)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by creating a `subclass` in actionscript 2, here's a great step-by-step tutorial from Adobe.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/mc_subclasses_v2_04.html

The tutorial instructs you to add an onEnterFrame event handler, but you can ignore that and simply add the following code to the constructor.

If your classname is `Ball` then the code would look like this. (this is from step 4 in the tutorial).

```
dynamic class Ball extends MovieClip {

  function Ball() {
    this._alpha = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something I didn't understood correctly, but you just have to write something like this on your first frame :

```
yourFirstMovieClip._alpha = 0;
yourSecondMovieClip._alpha = 0;
```

---

If your MovieClips names are numbered (mc0, mc1, mc2, mc3...), you can use a loop to set the _alpha property to every clips.
Let say you have 5 clips (mc0 to mc4) :

```
for( var i:Number = 0  ;  i < 5  ;  i++ )
{
    this["mc"+i]._alpha = 0;
}
```

---

If not, you can store every clips in an Array and them loop through it :

```
var clips:Array = [mcFirst, mcSecond, mcThird, mcFourth];
for( var i:Number = 0  ;  i < clips.length  ;  i++ )
{
   clips[i]._alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to write the code in one place inside the MC without naming the instances directly. That way i can just add as many MC's as i like and never have to worry about modifying the code.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to put this line on the first frame of your MovieClip :

```
_alpha = 0;
```

Start your animation on the second frame, and add the following line on your last one :

```
gotoAndPlay( 2 );
```

So the code on the first frame is only executed one time.

Comment: I did consider this, and even tried it out. But i am adding to someone existing code. Something was causing it to re-execute regardless so hoped for another way of doing it.